# MPMoviePlayerViewController and background audio

Tags: iphone, background, audio-streaming

I am having trouble playing audio inside a MPMoviePlayerViewController in the background. I can point it to mp3's just fine and listen to the audio, but when I go into the background, I don't hear audio anymore.

I set the plist entry to keep playing audio and set the audio session to`AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`. When I hit the home button, wait a few seconds, and go back to the app, the audio advanced as if it had kept playing, I just can't hear a thing when the app is in the background.

Any idea what causes this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested in the simulator, and it fails there. It does work fine on the device though. Must be a bug in the simulator.